# Store non-English string in std::string

Tags: c++, string, encoding, stdstring, wstring

I have a simple string in `std::wstring`

```
std::wstring tempStr = _T("F:\\Projects\\Current_자동_\\Cam.xml");
```

I want to store this string in a `std::string`.

I have tried the below code but the result is not the same as input string

```
std::wstring tempStr = _T("F:\\Projects\\Current_자동_\\Cam.xml");
//setup converter
typedef  std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 <wchar_t> convert_type;
std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

//use converter (.to_bytes: wstr->str, .from_bytes: str->wstr)
std::string converted_str = converter.to_bytes( tempStr );
```

The Korean string present in the input string is converted to `"ìžë™"`.

Is there any way I can get the same string in std::string?

**Expected result:**

`converted_str` should contain **F:\Projects\Current_자동_\Cam.xml**

Below is an screenshot of debugging showing 3 values in 3 scenarios (conversion in 3 ways). But none of them gives the desired value.

[image: Debugging image]

Comment: Start with checking your improper escapes. `\P`, `\C`, etc. You need dbl-slashes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am concerned about the non-english characters!

Comment: That is the same string. It is encoded in UTF-8, and when you print that UTF-8 data as Latin-1 you get `"ìžë™`. If you want to see `자동` then you need to print it as UTF-8. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, it is the same string but in this case the path is getting changed and because of this I am not able to load/access the file.

Comment: @Narendra: since the question is really about opening files, you should show the code where you open the file. That's what needs to change, since the encoding it gets isn't what it expects.

Comment: @SteveJessop Because of the Korean string present in the path the std::string is able to store the proper path and due to which file is not accessible.

Comment: @Narendra: the encoding you use must match the encoding expected by the file open function you use

Comment: Visual Studio's debugger is not printing the string correctly. That does not mean the string was not converted correctly. Like @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think you should be looking at the file open function you are trying to use and forget about what the debugger thinks the string means.

Comment: You need to realize how encoding works. A character set gets encoded into bytes when it gets stored in a string or a file. For ASCII characters, this is a simple conversion where one character becomes one byte. But since other character sets, like Unicode, have more than 256 characters, they need multiple bytes per character. The most trustworthy way to look at the encoded bytes is by printing their hex values, as others on this page do. This is because if you ask visual studio to print the string's content for you, it won't know that it is a Unicode string and won't know how to decode it.

Comment: Even when you print the string to stdout, what you see on your terminal depends on your operating system's settings. If you're watching through an ssh terminal, it depends on the client OS's settings, those of the ssh terminal software, and those of the remote system's OS. When you check in your code to version control, same problem. Encoding is complicated. Or messy rather...

Comment: the default settings for the Visual C++ debugger are to not display Unicode characters. There is a check box under Tools / Options / Debug labeled "Display unicode strings" which turns this on.

Answer (score 4):

Your conversion code is fine.

In fact, in UTF-8 (the string you store in `std::string`), the characters 자동 corresponds to:

> ```
> 자 (UTF-16 0xC790) ---> UTF-8:  EC 9E 90
> 동 (UTF-16 0xB3D9) ---> UTF-8:  EB 8F 99
> ```

If you run the following program, which just prints the converted UTF-8 bytes, you get this output:

> ```
> ec 9e 90 eb 8f 99
> ```

---

```
#include <iomanip>      // For std::hex
#include <iostream>     // For console output
#include <string>       // For STL strings
#include <codecvt>      // For Unicode conversions

void print_char_hex(const char ch)
{
    auto * p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&ch);
    int i = *p;
    std::cout << std::hex << i << ' ';
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring utf16_str = L"\xC790\xB3D9";

    // setup converter
    typedef  std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t> convert_type;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_type, wchar_t> converter;

    // use converter (.to_bytes: wstr->str, .from_bytes: str->wstr)
    std::string converted_str = converter.to_bytes( utf16_str );

    // Output the converted bytes (UTF-8)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < converted_str.length(); ++i)
    {
        print_char_hex(converted_str[i]);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I ran this code using utf16_str = "F:\\Projects\\Current_자동_\\Cam.xml"    but 자동 was not in the output.

Comment: As you can note, I entered the corresponding UTF-16 encoding of the Korean characters you used. I tend to use pure ASCII in C++ source code. If you want to enter the Korean characters directly in source code, you may want to try saving the source file with UTF-16 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to use the wide-char APIs to open the file, e.g. `CreateFileW(...);`, because then you can use the wide-char file name directly.

If this is not possible, maybe the string should not be converted to UTF8, but to the system default ANSI code page.
I think this might work:

```
    char out[200];
    wchar_t * in = L"F:\\Projects\\Current_자동_\\Cam.xml";
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
```

or maybe another Korean code page:

```
    WideCharToMultiByte(949, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(1361, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(10003, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(20833, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(20949, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(50225, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(50933, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(51949, 0, in, 100, out, 100, 0, 0);
```

The code page ids can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works.. You can tell because the conversion back to UTF16 is valid.. If you write the UTF8 string to a file, it will also display properly. This way, you now have two ways of validating that it works.

```
// UTF16ToUTF8.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>

std::wstring ToUTF16(const std::string &data)
{
    return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().from_bytes(data);
}

std::string ToUTF8(const std::wstring &data)
{
    return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(data);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring u16 = L"_자동_";
    std::string u8 = ToUTF8(u16);

    MessageBoxW(NULL, ToUTF16(u8).c_str(), L"", 0);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store UTF-8 in `std:string` as regular char sequence. Here's library with some useful things, such as `length()` and everything about indexing, you may want to have http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/.

For windows console you need to set codepage to `65001` and will become UTF-8.

Sadly or not, `std::wstring` and whole `wchar_t` thing doesn't specify any specific encoding.

By the way, you're using Managed C++, why wouldn't you use .NET Framework's `System::String^`? There's no problems with encodings at all. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp

Answer (score -1):

The problem is not in your string conversion code. This is a typical source file encoding problem. Visual studio does not use Unicode as default so you should convert your source file's encoding to UTF-8 yourself. To make this conversion you can open your file with notepad++ and click  Encoding->Convert to UTF-8

Note1: In VS2010 and vs2012 if you write non-ascii characters to a source file visual studio now warns you and offers to make this conversion.

Note2: From your use of macro _T() I predict this is targeted only to Windows. If you try to build UTF-8 encoded source files that contains BOM with gcc you may get different errors. In any case the best approach would be to read your UTF-8 encoded text data from a file during run-time.